# Changing onMouseOver with .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, attributes, onmouseover

So, I have this `opDiv1` set as `onMouseOver="mhover(opDiv1)"` but I want to change the function `onMouseOver` if the browser is IE.

I'm using this:

```
if (ie!=undefined) { //If IE detected
        $('#opDiv1').attr("onMouseOver","mhover_ie('opDiv1')")
}
```

However, if I use IE (any version) it doesn't change `onMouseOver`'s function

Comment: why dont you just bind the functions directly using `jQuery` that way you benefit from any cross browser compatibility `jQuery` provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change IE's onMouseOver-event this way

```
if (ie != undefined) {
    document.getElementById('opDiv1').onmouseover = function () { mhover_ie('opDiv1'); };
};
```

**Info:**
Assigning a function to the onclick property does not add an attribute to the DOM node.

Comment: Tried but it gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null"

Comment: Is the DOM already loaded? It sounds like your DOM isn't ready and then there is no Element "opDiv1"

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
Remove the `attr onmouseover` from the obj, and `bind` the event with `jQuery` like:

```
function addMouseEvent(){
    if (ie!=undefined) { //If IE detected
            $('#opDiv1').onmouseover(function(){
              mhover_ie('opDiv1');
            });
    } else {
            $('#opDiv1').onmouseover(function(){
              mhover('opDiv1');
            });
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  addMouseEvent();
});
```

Comment: This gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onmouseover'"

Comment: Well as any jQuery function to `DOM` elements, must wait until the document is ready... answer edited ;-)